# Building AutoHotKey shortcut

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

I've recently found AutoHotKey as an extremely valid tool to increase my productivity with keyboard but I'm unable to bind a shortcut and I can't figure out why.

I'd like to have a shortcut to type È seamlessly and so I thought of using AutoHotKey with the following code:

```
+è::È
```

The problem with this is that if now I need to type `{` (which is done via AltGr-Shift-è) I get `È`, as if the AltGr wasn't read by the system. The issue is solved by adding explicitly the hotkey for {

```
<^>!+è::È
+è::È
```

I don't understand why, if I use the first script, is as if the AltGr key is not read when I type it and so AltGr-Shift-è types `È` instead of `{`

Comment: Have you tried a single `*+è::È` line instead?

Comment: Yes, but even if it had worked it remains the problem, why the AltGr key is not considered in case I want to type {...

Answer (score 0):

Let me throw in a totally different approach:

```
:*C:`e::è ; first type ` then e to get è
:*C:`E::È ; first type ` then E to get È
```

Comment: I solved as I said in the answer, it was much more practical and easy.. thx by the way :-)